# How do I make a UITextField adjust its size appropriately depending on the iPhone being used?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I would like my `UITextField`s to use up most of the screen. I've tried setting constraints on the text fields but this doesn't work. I'm testing using an iPhone 5s and a 6.

Getting a decent size on the iPhone 5s leaves big spaces on each side of the `UITextField`s on an iPhone 6; when I set the desired sizes on the iPhone 6, the `UITextField`s are too big for the screen on the iPhone 5s.

I thought the same principle that I use when setting up scroll views, etc. applies. These `UITextField`s are in in scroll views, and I have no issue with the scroll views using the different devices.

I've tried size to fit but this makes the text fields too small. I would provide code but I've done this all in Interface Builder.

[image]

[image]

These fields are within the contentView for my scrollView.

I don't mind either Objective-C or Swift answers.

Comment: Could you add a screen shot showing the constrains you used?

Comment: Have you pinned the leading and trailing spaces of the text field?

Comment: Added a screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Auto Layout automatically figures out the content size of your scrollView for you based upon its contents.  If you don't tell it the width of your contentView, it must figure this out by the constraints on the items in the scrollView.  Even though your textViews are pinned to the left and right of the scrollView, you are forced to specify their widths so that Auto Layout can figure out how wide to make the content of your scrollView. To solve this, add a contentView to your scrollView that will be the single top level item in the scrollView. All other items will be added as subviews of the contentView.

1. Add a contentView to your scrollView.  Pin its left, top, right, and bottom edges to the scrollView.  Constrain its width to be equal to the scrollView's width.  To do that, open the Document Outline View, control drag from the view contained by the scroll view to the scroll view and then select "Equal Widths" from the pop-up. Constrain its height to be big enough for all of your content.  This will allow the scrollView to scroll vertically only.
2. Constrain your textViews trailing and leading edges to the contentView.  Their width will stretch automatically to fill the space on each phone.

Comment: I have a contentView. I didn't set the constraints like I normally do because the scrolling seemed to work without doing so. I will give this a try now.

Comment: Errors gone: http://tinypic.com/r/2f0btp4/8 but still no luck wiht layout: http://tinypic.com/r/2duh8nc/8

Comment: Is your scrollView pinned to top, bottom, left and right of the top level view?

Comment: The bottom, left and right are. The top is pinned to a segmented control. That sits just below the navigation bar.

Comment: Did you remember to constrain the contentView width to equal to the scrollView width?  It still looks like your contentView is wider than the scrollView.

Comment: My contentView has a width of 600.  The scrollView is pinned to the top level view. Not sure what's going on. I could centre a view and set fixed sizes for the fields to accommodate the iPhone 5 but this will leave bigger gaps on the iPhone 6.

Comment: Do you have a constraint that is setting the contentView width to 600?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68384/discussion-between-vacawama-and-londonguy).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have single text field . Then you have to apply following constraint to fulfil all the constraints :

1. Left spacing
2. Right spacing
3. Top spacing
4. width
5. height

The width and height constraints are most important one . When all constraints are fulfilled then lines will become blue. Try this .

Comment: Hi, yep this is what I understood but I was under the impression if I set the width then the textfield would become a fixed size. So for example if I set a wide width to accommodate the iPhone 6 then wouldn't it be too big when using the iPhone 5?

Comment: here width and height means width and height constraints . Is it same that you mean ? @LondonGuy